# How to prevent Session Lost in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, session

I have Xubuntu 14.04. Every time my montor is locked down due to inactivity, my current session is getting lost as if I am logging out.

I was downloading a file from internet. And after specific amount of time, my monitor got locked. When I unlocked the monitor , I found that new session has begun as if I am logging into new session.

Please help on how to prevent from logging out / session loss.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Open `xfce4-session-settings` and activate this option:

[image]

More options which could be useful in this case you will find in the `light-locker-settings` menu:

[image]

You can completely disable auto logging out if you disable light-locker.